# Convert 2-level factor to TRUE / FALSE

Tags: r, r-factor

I have to convert this class to True and False

```
Class          : Factor w/ 2 levels "benign","malignant": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
```

I already tried it to convert it to a numeric, by

```
as.numeric(BreastCancer$Class)
as.integer(BreastCancer$Class)
```

then I did

```
as.logical(BreastCancer$Class)
```

but I only get NA's.

I tried to use the install packages `dplyr` for recoding, but I can not figure out how that works.

Comment: I got all my 1 and 2 as NA's so i did something wrong, so no dont want to keep them

Answer (score 1):

It is important to keep track of what you are coding as `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
vec_factor <- factor(
  c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  labels = c("benign", "malignant")
)
str(vec_factor)
# Factor w/ 2 levels "benign","malignant": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1

vec_logical <- as.logical(as.integer(vec) == 1)
str(vec_logical)
# logi [1:10] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE ...
```

**Update:**

As @zx8754 commented, `as.logical` is redundant:

```
str(as.integer(vec) == 1)
# logi [1:10] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE ...
```

and @李哲源's answer is much more elegant.

Comment: benign is code as 1 and i want to code that to TRUE

Comment: No need for `as.logical`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply:

```
BreastCancer$ClassLogical <- BreastCancer$Class == "benign"
```